# Sorting a ranges rows depending on a certain Columns value which is provided by another table

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, formatting

So what I am trying to do is auto sort on edit a row within a range of data depending on a certain fields input.

[image]

So on the image above I would like to order Column F depending on the Table in Column S
I have put a Rank tally from 1 to 18 in Column T

a VLookup is working in Column O
This works like so `=VLOOKUP(F9,$S$11:$T$28,2,false)`
I was going to use this Tally to sort the other Rows in the table to the Sort is applied to Column 0 in the table depending on the value in Column F

This is what I have so far

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var SHEETNAME = 'Sheetname'
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME )
  
  var columnToSortBy = 15;
  var tableRange = "B9:Q33"; // What to sort. 

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){ 
  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );}
}
```

In theory this should work but I'm not sure if the formula is interfering in the sort.
If it is the formula does anyone know how to write such a formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi so after no responses I went back to the drawing board and figured this out.

I kept the formula in Row O which revered to table 2 and then did a 'Record Macro'.

This then provided this:

```
function SortColumnOin69th() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('O8').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(15, true);
};
```

The Macro is quite simple it sorts a certain column in a range. the sort is applied to column 15 (Row 0) and affects the whole table.

So now when I edit the Rank column in row F it now moves the columns into order depending on the rank location.